# Is there a recomended approach in order to edit photos?

Tags: photo-editing, image-editing

My question is not about *how* to edit a photo, but trying to understand which guidelines are used to achieve best results.
I'm sure there are people studying this field.

I think it's wrong the approach to play around with random combinations of settings, crossing fingers to see sooner or later the image you like...it's more like brute force attack, not the best.

So, is there a **recommended** methodology?

Comment: How long is a rope? This is a very broad question with as many answers as there are people working with photo editing. If you try to narrow down your question it will be easier to answer ;)

Comment: Yes there is a workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rigorous methodology would be in a closed environment. For example, if you work with one particular client that want things done in a specific way, yes, you probably have one "rigorous" methodology, probably a square one.

"Recommended" methodology can be a better approach. Yes, there are some elements that can be in a recommended order. For example, *normally* I would leave the resampling of one photo and some sharpening as the last step, just before or even during the exporting to the desired size.

But there can be the case where one person needs to do resampling as a first step, probably because he is working with a zillion images that need to be stitched together or has a slow machine, or they are unsure of what the next process is and needs a mockup done...

---

Some general rules **can** be:

- Shoot in RAW.
- Try to get the exposure right on the shot, know your gear.
- Backup your images before processing.

---

Editing:

1. First corrective things that should have been done in the shot. Exposure and white balance. Add some intrinsic failures of the lens.

   - Turn on lens aberrations corrections, like chromatic aberrations.
   - Correct general exposure
   - Correct color temperature and tint.
2. Correcting what cannot be naturally captured by the camera: dynamic range, shadows, and highlight ratio.

   - Adjust the brightness by zones, blacks, whites, shadows, highlights.
   - Adjust corrective sharpening and noise. By corrective, I mean some blurred specific zones that were out of focus.
3. Leave the subjective color adjustments to the last. This is not corrections, these are adjustments.

   - Adjust color; saturation, vibrancy (and "clarity" if you are using Lightroom)
   - Define the mood, some styles. Add vignetting, add some DOF.
4. Leave additional, accidental, specific viewing conditions, as a later additional step.

   - Resample and overall sharpening.
   - Change color mode (CMYK)

Obviously, this is not carved in stone.

---

And as "editing" can refer to different things, like making compositing (here is an example)

[image]

<sub>Original image: https://www.deviantart.com/fantasystock/art/Industrial-Foundry-03-154840734</sub>

and after obvious steps like masking the elements:

- Define your scale
- Define the contrast
- Define the color
- Merge using shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you already know all common technical tricks such as making adjustments and corrections. You have no problem to make technically as good photos as the original shot allows. You adjust white balance, correct perspective, lift up details from shadows, recover too bright areas etc...Also you can crop an unwanted part out of the image, remove some disturbing details and insert something from another image - everything which can be seen as a part of the photo editing skill set.

But when the camera was aimed towards something and the trigger was pressed, the shooter hopefully had some reason for it. He hopefully decided that this miniscule portion of the reality catched by the camera is worth to be seen later. He had an idea of impression which he wanted to be possible to create - maybe a vague and only coarsely defined one, but so strong that he shooted to that particular direction, not elsewhere.

You as a photo editor have a possiblity to spoil shooter's ideas for example by removing something, making it unsharp or lifting up something that the shooter didn't even notice. You can change the weights of the things. It's not only the objects in the image, you can also affect their relations. Actually you can sometimes even create an impression of a relation which in reality was non-existent. An example: Turn a little one's eyes and deform his mouth to make him to seem to like or dislike something.

For succesful editing you should start by deciding what impression the shooter wanted to create. You can probably make it stronger if you want. Then you must have your own idea, what impression you want to create. It can be the one which you guessed the shooter wants or something else. You cannot affect the shooting, but you can select between different shots, edit details and make combinations. The idea of the wanted impression is a must. Otherwise your edits have no goal.

You may notice that you need better knowledge of means to present relations. For that purpose explore existing images and practice.